# не получаеться вывести CAN сообщение

Tags: c, сокет, структуры

```
void processFrame(const struct canfd_frame& frame) {
    int len = 0;
    unsigned char data[8];

    printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame.can_id);
    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.len); len = frame.len;
    printf("len = %d", len);
    //printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%s] ", frame.data[i]);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = frame.data[i];
    printf("\n ---------------- \n");
    printf(" %03X ", frame.can_id );
     for (int i = 0; i < frame.len; ++i)
        {
            printf(" %02X", frame.data[i]);
        }
    //---//
}
```

Вот сама структура

```
typedef __u32 canid_t;
typedef unsigned int __u32;
typedef unsigned char __u8;


struct canfd_frame {
    canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
    __u8    len;     /* frame payload length in byte */
    __u8    flags;   /* additional flags for CAN FD */
    __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

Как бы всё прекрасно выводиться кроме 'frame.data[i]' , почему-то "завершает" программу.

вот результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так выглядит когда я вывожу сообщение без 'frame.data[i]'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **`%s`**  в `for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%s] ", frame.data[i]);` это ошибка. У вас ведь в `.data[]` вовсе не указатели

Comment: @avp извините, но что тогда надо ввести ??? `[%d]` также побывал программа не отрабатывает.

Comment: И что происходит  при %d ?